# Stop spool printing the sql query used (Oracle)

Tags: oracle11g, sqlplus, spool

I have this running in SQLplus

```
set feedback off
set pagesize 0
spool TypeDrop.sql
select distinct 'drop type '||object_name|| ';' from user_objects where object_type='TYPE';
spool off
```

It prints out to TypeDrop.sql:

```
SQL> select distinct 'drop type '||object_name||';' from user_objects where object_type='TYPE';
drop type ADDRESS_OBJTYP; 
drop type PERSON_OBJTYP;                                                                                                                                              
SQL> spool off
```

How do i get it to just output the `drop` statements? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running from within a script, `set termout off` works. It doesnt if you are just typing into the terminal.

create myScript.sql:

```
set feedback off
set pagesize 0
set termout off
spool TypeDrop.sql
select distinct 'drop type '||object_name|| ';' from user_objects where object_type='TYPE';
spool off
```

and from your sqlplus prompt:

```
SQL> @myScript
```

will do the trick.

Answer (score 10):

Use `sqlplus -s`. The `-s` flag means silent

Answer (score -1):

try

```
set echo off
```